# Nested List Appending in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nested

I'm trying to write a function that will append a given value to the innermost lists of a nested list structure, but I'm running into errors with type when I'm not even sure what the type signature of such a function would be.

```
digpend a xs = case xs of [_:_] -> map (digpend a) xs
                          [[]]  -> [[a]]
                          xs    -> a:xs
```

For example,

```
digpend 555 [ [ [ 5,1,-12,33 ] , [ 6,22 ] ] , [ [ -9,0,9,12,83 ] ] ]
```

should return

```
[ [ [ 555,5,1,-12,33 ] , [ 555,6,22 ] ] , [ [ 555,-9,0,9,12,83 ] ] ]
```

and ideally, it would work on any level of nesting by recursion. Is this allowed?

Comment: @AndrewC: I can’t quite see how yet, but it might be manageable using multiparameter type classes, no?  The fact that `(digpend a)` wants to be polymorphic isn’t necessarily a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a not-entirely-satisfactory implementation, using type classes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class DigPend a b where
  digpend :: a -> [b] -> [b]

instance DigPend a a where
  digpend x xs = (x:xs)

instance (DigPend a b) => (DigPend a [b]) where
  digpend x xs = map (digpend x) xs
```

It works well, as long as the type of the arguments is fully specified:

```
*Main> digpend (5 :: Int) ([6,7,8] :: [Int])
[5,6,7,8]
*Main> digpend (555 :: Int) ([[[5,1,-12,33],[6,22]],[[-9,0,9,12,83]]] :: [[[Int]]])
[[[555,5,1,-12,33],[555,6,22]],[[555,-9,0,9,12,83]]]
*Main> digpend (5 :: Int) ([] :: [Int])
[5]
*Main> digpend (5 :: Int) ([] :: [[Int]])
[]
```

However, an invocation like `digpend 5 [6,7,8]` triggers lots of “ambiguous type variable” errors — a numeric literal like `5` is polymorphic (it can inhabit any instance of `Num`), and while `ghci` would usually happily default to `Integer`, it first tries to solve the type class constraints for `DigPend`, and at that stage, there is not enough type information for it to know which instance of `digpend` to apply.

Answer (score 4):

Solving this will require a bit of type-level programming skills and some GHC extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class Digpend a d where
  digpend :: a -> d -> d

instance (Digpend a d) => Digpend a [d] where
  digpend a list = map (digpend a) list

instance Digpend a [a] where
  digpend a list = a : list

main = do
  -- We have to help the compiler disambiguate the numbers by putting explicit
  -- type signatures:
  print $ digpend 
    (555 :: Int) 
    ([ [ [ 5,1,-12,33 ] , [ 6,22 ] ] , [ [ -9,0,9,12,83 ] ] ] :: [[[Int]]])
  -- In case of specific literals, such as `Char`, it's not a problem though.
  print $ digpend '!' [['a', 'b', 'c'], "def"]
```

Results in:

```
[[[555,5,1,-12,33],[555,6,22]],[[555,-9,0,9,12,83]]]
["!abc","!def"]
```

Comment: Interesting that we came to almost exactly the same solution!  I wonder if there’s any approach that doesn’t require the explicit disambiguation?

Comment: @PLL The ambiguity problem is not the problem of our solutions, but of the fact that numeric literals are inferred as `Num a => a`. Since our classes are polymorphic, the compiler can't use them to disambiguate it. In real life usage it won't be a problem though, since chances are this function will be used in a specific context, from which the compiler will be able to infer a specific type. There is also a possibility to infer either of the parameters based on another one by utilizing functional dependencies.

Comment: the ambiguity isn’t just from the numeric literals, since normally ghc(i) will happily either keep them polymorphic or choose defaults for them; it’s an interaction of some kind between this polymorphism and our slightly tricky flexible instances. It also won’t necessarily go away in real life usage, since polymorphic functions certainly don’t.  Functional dependency could be a nice way to try to improve things, yes (though the class we’ve currently defined isn’t functional in either direction, so it doesn’t directly apply to our current approach).

Answer (score 2):

If you can/are allowed to define your own data type, you can also use the following:

```
data Tree a = Leaves [a] | InnerNodes [Tree a] deriving (Show)

digpend :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
digpend x (Leaves xs) = Leaves $ x:xs
digpend x (InnerNodes []) = InnerNodes [Leaves [x]]
digpend x (InnerNodes xs) = InnerNodes . map (digpend x) $ xs
```

Some output examples:

```
*Main> digpend 10 $ InnerNodes [ Leaves [], Leaves [], InnerNodes []]
InnerNodes [Leaves [10],Leaves [10],InnerNodes [Leaves [10]]]
*Main> digpend 555 $ InnerNodes [InnerNodes [Leaves [5, 1, -12, 33], Leaves [6, 22]], InnerNodes [Leaves [-9, 0, 9, 12, 83]]]
InnerNodes [InnerNodes [Leaves [555,5,1,-12,33],Leaves [555,6,22]],InnerNodes [Leaves [555,-9,0,9,12,83]]]
```